# How can I create registration form and how can I get what the users filled in that form in my FB app

Tags: php, facebook

I have created one app in facebook (using facebook canvas). It is working properly, but I want to know, how can I put a registration form with some fields???

I have written the code for form,

```
<form action="../form/fbform.php" method="post">
My Name
<input maxlength="50" name="name" type="text" value="" />
My Email 
<input maxlength="50" name="email" type="text" value="" />
I Work for
<input maxlength="50" name="cmpny" type="text" value="" />
My Friend
<input maxlength="50" name="frdname" type="text" value="" />
My Friend's Email
<input maxlength="50" name="frdemail" type="text" value="" />

<input name="try" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

That is the code for my form, but after submission it showing blank page.

In action I have written fbform.php, In that file, I have the written the sql code to insert these form details into my website database. and also I have written redirect url to my app. but it's not working.

How can put the registration form in my app and how can I get those details (what users filled in those fields) in my website database or some excel sheet??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to see the fbml tags to post your data to your desired web page and try the GET method and use the session object of the facebook to retrieve your details .

```
<form action="../form/fbform.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="test1"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_session_key" value=”<?php $_GET[‘fb_sig_session_key’]”></input>
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value=”<?php $_GET[‘user_id’]”></input>
<input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
</form>
```